# How to draw the graph of two curves look like a lemniscate which satisfy $d_1d_2=b$ where $b<a^2$ and $b>a^2$ respectively?

Tags: calculus, polar-coordinates

Actually I was drawing the graph of a lemniscate with the help of a polar ordinate equation - $r^2=2a^2cos2\theta$
And for which I had to prove that the points lie on it would satisfy the condition $d_1d_2=a^2$
Where $d_1,d_2$ and $a$ for a point $P$ lie on the lamniscate are shown in the following figure [it is the figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2PLCi.png)

Now I am looking for the graph of two curves which satisfy $d_1d_2=b$ where $b>a^2$ and $b<a^2$ respectively.Please help me.

Comment: The polar coordinate equation of the lemniscate is $r^2=a^2cos\left(2\theta\right)$. Isn't it?

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! <> Just checking: Do you know how to find Cartesian coordinates of a point on a polar equation, and how to find the distance between two points in Cartesian form?

Comment: @YNK sorry for the mistake, I've updated the question.

Comment: @Andrew D. Hwang actually I have alredy drawn the graphs and want to check them only.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cassini_oval    Disjointed ovals are separated from single ovals by Bernoulli Lemniscate.

Comment: @Narasimham Thank you very much to prove me right.